# Unexpected Token Import in <script> tag of HTML file

Tags: javascript, java

I have been searching for quite a while with this. I am trying to `import java.util.*` but it isn't working. My file is a `.html` and the import statement is inside a `<script>` tag. I noticed when trying different packages, on j`ava.lang.Math`, the word Math did not change to blue as is usually would. I am getting the error message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.

Comment: Post your code. From what I can piece together, you're trying to import java into an HTML file, which is not how Java works.

Comment: *"I am trying to import java.util.\*"* and *"My file is a .html"* are statements that really don't connect to each other. You use `import` in a Java file, not an HTML file. Are you using JSP or something?

Comment: I'm pretty new to java. I'm trying to build a web page and usually I would use PHP but I can't right now so I am trying java. The place I am using import is inside a <script> tag, so I thought that was the same as being in a java file. If I make a .java file, how do I open it as a web page and write to the document? Also, how do I post my code? I am new to stack overflow

Comment: I was just informed that I have been misusing java and javascript. So now my question is concerning how to use imports with javascript

Comment: Don't take it bad but because your understanding of Java and JavaScript was fundamentally incorrect, I think that before asking a question on a precise technical point (*"how to import in Javascript"*) that you might not need, you should rather explain what you want to achieve globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in comments and answer JavaScript and Java are [**two distinct languages**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java). Their concepts are quite different while their names are similar.

Since Java is more used on the server side or to create standalone application  and you seem to intend to create a small page probably making some calculations, JavaScript *seems* to be more adapted (...without knowing what you precisely want).

You should first [learn its fundamentals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) and also have a look at the [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) global object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tags you have used for this question, I am assuming that you think javascript and java the same. THEY ARE NOT. Javascript and java are totally different things.

Comment: technically, you can now yes

Comment: @Alexandre Really? I didn't know. But I think he sees javascript and java as same, that's why

Comment: could you please explain the difference or post a link to something that does? you are right, I was under the impression they are the same

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml See this, but better google it, you can find better explanations

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Is there a way to import in javascript then?

Comment: I don't know, I think something like JSP or something would be the way, but I have no understanding of that. You could just surf on the net and easily find a way. Just a simple search like: "How to import java packages into javascript" would do.

Comment: @BhavikVagadia You said "CANNOT use an import in javascript" and this, especially this point, is not true https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a better way that you know of to go about this? I am just trying to build a relatively simple website but I need the java.util.ArrayList class. Would it be easier to use a different language?

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi I see that, i didn't know about that, I have edited it. Thank you for the note however

Comment: @AustinD I myself don't know how to go about it. If you are to research it yourself, it would be better because you know better about your requirements. Also, searching about such things is a better practice for a developer. I hope someone could comment you exactly what you want, because I am as ignorant as you on this.